# MCMC estimation in mixed models: is there something like "significance"?

Tags: mixed-model, markov-chain-montecarlo

I am a bit confused in determining whether to keep or remove some of the random coefficients in a mixed model. There are quite few level two units, therefore I have to use MCMC estimation. As result, standard errors for most variables in the random part are about 60% of the corresponding point estimate. On the other hand, DIC for the whole model is substantially reduced when adding each variable separately to the random part.

As far as I understand modeling with ML, if a standard error greater than about half of the point estimate value, it is a sign that the respective coefficient is insignificant. Can I interpret the standard error in MCMC the same way? If so, what takes precedence, DIC or estimate/standard error ratio?

I am a beginner with respect to mixed models, so any references for self-education will be appreciated along with the eventual explanation. Thank you!

ADDENDUM:

To make the question more clear with an example:

[Case one](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18527706/mcmc1.png)
[Case two](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18527706/mcmc2.png)

In the first case I am inclined to accept the parameter, given that its mode is far from zero and 95% credible intervals are 2.2 and 11.1. In the second case I am inclined to reject the parameter, particularly looking at the kernel density graph. Zero has almost as high probability as the mode. However, 95% credible intervals are 0.002 and 0.012. If I only look at these I feel I should retain the parameter. The left bound is close to zero, but the estimate itself is not that large; and it is an interaction effect, so this size makes sense. In addition, DIC for the whole model goes down by about 50, which is quite a lot. Mixed signals, so to speak, at least they seem to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of confidence intervals, Bayesian analysis uses credible intervals. So you could take a particular bound that you think is significant and calculate the percentage that the parameter falls in that region. I find credible intervals far more intuitive than frequentist confidence intervals. Also, since you're doing a MCMC, you can also plot histograms of the parameter values to get a sense of how different the posterior is from any quantity of interest, such as zero.

Comment: I believe that when John says "how different the posterior is from zero," he is using zero as a stand-in for any quantity of interest.

Comment: @user777 I made an edit based on your suggestion.

Comment: @John First of all, thank you for a quick response. I am not sure how am I to interpret CI in borderline cases. E.g. when kernel density plot shows relatively high probability for zero, whereas CI do not include it. I have edited my original post to include specific examples, and would really appreciate your comments.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the software you're using or what the model you're estimating is, so I'm afraid I can't add too much to what I've said. I think what really matters is if you think something is significant enough and if you can defend yourself calling it significant in a paper or to a boss. Anyway, your models appear to be bounded by zero at the lower end. That suggests that being different from zero may not be the most relevant metric. It's like if I estimate a normal inverse gamma model and look at the probability of the variance being bigger than zero. It will be 100%, not informative.

Comment: @John Solid guess, both are variance parameters :) But why is that difference from zero is irrelevant? If it is variance on the second level, being different from zero indicates that there is some intra-class correlation. If it has a good chance of being zero, then I can simplify my model. Or am I still thinking in frequentist terms? The software is MLwiN by the way, and I think it gives posterior distribution in the right top corner.

Comment: @Maxim.K Because variance can't be less than zero. Even if you were to perform a frequentist test, such as a chi-square test, you wouldn't be comparing variance relative to zero. You compare variance relative to a particular value.